# Vsftpd запущена но не слушает порт

Tags: linux, vsftpd

команда

```
systemctl status vsftpd
```

ответ

```
vsftpd.service - LSB: Very secure FTP server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/vsftpd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-04-19 08:37:00 MSK; 3min 21s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 23640 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/vsftpd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 21853 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
```

Вроде всё ок `Active: active` но напрягает `code=killed` команда:

```
netstat -anp | grep LISTEN
```

Говорит что никто не слушает ни 20 ни 21 порты.

Comment: `ps ax | grep -i ftp` ? `ss -tunap | grep -i ftp` ?

Comment: `но напрягает code=killed` - правильно напрягает. netstat grep должен был показать запись про 21-й порт (20-го не будет, он задействован только в момент передачи данных). К тому же Main `PID: 21853 (code=killed, signal=TERM)` - главный процесс прибит.

Comment: посмотри логи. возможно там есть ответы на твой вопрос.